# Question about normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am stuck on this question:

> Let $f: G \rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism.  Suppose $H$ is abelian.  Let $N$ be a subgroup of $G$ that contains $\ker f$.  Prove that $N \trianglelefteq G$.

### This is my attempt:

Since $H$ abelian, $f(G)$ is abelian. So, by $1^{st}$ isomorphism theorem $G/\ker f \cong f(G)$.

Now, let $a \in G, n\in N,$ I claim that $an=na$ for all $a \in G$ and $n \in N$.
 To see that, assume for the contrary there exists $a \in G$, $n \in N$ such that $an \neq na$. Clearly, $n \notin N$ because otherwise will contradicts theorem 5.5 that says $\ker f \unlhd G$. So we must have $n \in N$ such that $n \notin \ker f$.

I know that $f(an)=f(na)$ because of the property of an abelian group, but I could not see here any contradiction since we don't know anything about $f$ except it is a group homomorphism.

I would appreciate any help with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to prove that $aN = Na$, not that $an = na$ for all $n\in N$. The latter need not be true - e.g. take $G = N$ with $G$ not abelian.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $G/\operatorname{Ker} f$ is abelian. Then $N/\operatorname{Ker} f$ is a subgroup of an abelian group and is therefore a normal subgroup of $G/\operatorname{Ker} f$. Therefore $N$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: "Therefore  is normal in ". Does it follow from the Lattice theorem?

Comment: Any subgroup of an abelian group is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Agree, but the last statement "Therefore  is normal in ." follows from "$/Ker $ is a subgroup of an abelian group and is therefore a normal subgroup of $/Ker$"  because $G/\ker f \cong f(G)$?

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon G\to H$ is a surjective group homomorphism, then the map $\Phi\colon K\to f(K)$ is a bijection between the set of all subgroups of $G$ containing $\ker f$ and the subgroups of $H$. Under this map normality of subgroups is preserved, in the sense that a subgroup $K$ of $G$ containing $\ker f$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $f(K)$ is normal in $H$.

Some textbooks name this result “correspondence theorem” or “$n$-th homomorphism theorem” (for some value of $n$).

In your case, the homomorphism is not necessarily surjective, but if you consider the surjective $f_0\colon G\to f(G)$ (the same as $f$, but with a different codomain), you have that $f(G)$ is abelian, hence every subgroup thereof is normal.

You can also prove the statement directly. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ containing $\ker f$; let $g\in G$ and $x\in N$. Then
$$
f(gxg^{-1})=f(g)f(x)f(g)^{-1}=f(x)
$$
due to $H$ being abelian. Therefore $x^{-1}(gxg^{-1})\in\ker f$, hence
$$
x^{-1}(gxg^{-1})\in N
$$
and therefore $gxg^{-1}\in N$.